# Amazon Elastic Container Service and Helm

Tags: amazon-ecs, helm3

Can we use helm installation methods in Amazon ECS? I want to install certain images on ECS containers how can I do that with Helm commands? Is it possible or we have to use ECR and docker images?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. Helm is for Kubernetes only. ECS is not Kubernetes.